Can I use a #10/3 cable for a 120V outlet?
I have an outside wire from an old water pump for a waterfall at my pond. Can I take the 10/3 wire (red,black,white and bare ground wire) and reduce it to 120 for my new pump? Or do I have to run a whole new line? Or could I use the 240 line and run that into a new breaker box at the pond and pull my 120 from the breaker box?

Or this? Tap Into a 20 Amp Circuit Wired w/10 AWG Wire?

Or this? Can different gauges of wire be used on the same circuit?

Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

10/3 is usually on a 30 amp breaker.  As long as white/neutral is connected to the neutral bus, then go for it after reducing the breaker to 15 or 20 amps.
A subpanel will also make sense for future use.  30 amps could power about 4 circuits, with lights being about half.
The 10/3 you have now has to be wet rated (UF), not romex/NM-B, or it has to be removed.
A /3 has two 120v wires plus the neutral and/or ground.  So a single hot(red/black) plus the neutral gives you a 120v circuit (plus the ground for safety).
Can cap/wire nut the hot not used.  Should also remove the unused hot from the breaker.
10/3 wire is harder to use and some receptacles/outlets might not allow it (too big to fit). You can pigtail (in the box) 12 gauge on the 10 gauge to fit the outlet.

@Chris  I am assuming this being outside, it is GFCI protected.  If older, then you will need to add either a GFCI breaker or outlets for protection.


Can I take the 10/3 wire (red,black,white and bare ground wire) and reduce it to 120 for my new pump?

Yes, you can cap of the red (or black) and use the other live with the neutral to get 120V.
But given that it's a 10 gauge wire it's likely on a 30Amp breaker and you'll need to downsize that to fit the outlet you are installing.

Or could I use the 240 line and run that into a new breaker box at the pond and pull my 120 from the breaker box?

this is also an option. And it gives you a handy place for an outdoor outlet .

Thanks for the response your thoughts are much appreciated. The more I think about it the more I like the idea of adding a breaker box.

@Chris  A sub panel/breaker does give you more options, and it can be rated for more than 30 amps.  A panel is rated for the max power/amps it can handle.  You must have a 30 amp or larger panel for a 30 amp feed breaker.  Breaker spaces are the important factor.

Assuming all local requirements are met for outdoor GFCI protection (and that you wire it properly for 120 service rather than the 240 it is now), then there is never going to be a code problem using a wire higher rated either in voltage or amperage than the application calls for.
